# Mechanize for Python and authorization without first getting a 401 error

Tags: python, http, authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to use Mechanize to automate interactions with a very picky legacy system. In particular, after the first login page the authorization must be sent with every request it knocks you out of the system. Unfortunately, Mechanize seems content on only sending the authorization after first getting a 401 Unauthorized error. Is there any way to have it send authorization every time?

Here's some sample code:

```
br.add_password("http://example.com/securepage", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "/MYREALM")
br.follow_link(link_to_secure_page) # where the url is the previous URL
```

Here's the response I get from debugging Mechanize:

```
send: 'GET /securepage HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: example.com\r\nReferer: http://example.com/home\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n'
header: Server: Tandy1000Web
header: Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2011 03:08:04 GMT
header: Connection: close
header: Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 06:00:00 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII
header: Content-Length: 210
header: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="/MYREALM"
header: Cache-control: no-cache
send: 'GET /securepage HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: example.com\r\nReferer: http://example.com/home\r\nConnection: close\r\nAuthorization: Basic VVNFUk5BTUU6UEFTU1dPUkQ=\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Tandy1000Web
header: Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2011 03:08:07 GMT
header: Connection: close
header: Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Dec 2011 03:08:06 GMT
header: Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 06:00:00 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Content-Length: 33333
header: Cache-control: no-cache
```

The problem is that contrary to what should happen in modern web application with a `GET` request, by hitting the 401 error first I get the wrong page. I've confirmed with CURL and urllib2 that if I hit the URL directly by passing in the auth header on the first request I get the correct page.

Any hints on how to tell mechanize to always send the auth headers and avoid the first 401 error? This needs to be fixed on the client side. I can't modify the server.

Comment: Negative. As of the writing of this comment (late July 2013), I have yet to find an answer. When I find an answer, or someone else provides one, I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: Since I last asked, I managed to work this out by adding a header.

Answer (score 2):

```
from base64 import b64encode
import mechanize

url = 'http://192.168.3.5/table.js'
username = 'admin'
password = 'password'

# I have had to add a carriage return ('%s:%s\n'), but
# you may not have to.
b64login = b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))

br = mechanize.Browser()

# # I needed to change to Mozilla for mine, but most do not
# br.addheaders= [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

br.addheaders.append( 
  ('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % b64login )
)

br.open(url)
r = br.response()
data = r.read()

print data
```